# Python plot dates using matplotlib

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, wxpython

I'm very beginner at Python and matplotlib but trying to learn! I would like to use matplotlib to plot some simple data from a CSV containing dates with a frequency. The X axis containing dates and Y containing the frequency. Example data from CSV:

```
2011/12/15,5
2011/12/11,4
2011/12/19,2
```

I checked the "matplotlib.sf.net/examples" out but appears all the test data is downloaded from a http get.  I would really appreciate if someone could guide me with some example code of how to read in (presumably using CSV reader) and display data in chart.

Thank you!!

Comment: how do you want the data represented? Histogram? Is the example data a copy and paste from the CSV file? I'm assuming you have the X and Y value in the same cell?

Comment: Also, is the data all on one row?

Comment: Harpal - Thanks for the response. Ideally it be great to have it in a line chart. That is correct regarding X and Y but I can massage the way its stored in the CSV to whatever format to make if its easier another way. Thank you.

Comment: actually each line has a data and a frequency so line one: 2011/12/15,5 line two: 2011/12/10,4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to keep my code as simple as possible and this is by no means elegant, but here you go:

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

### Making test CSV file ###
data = [['2011/12/15,5'],['2011/12/11,4'],['2011/12/19,2'],['2011/12/16,3'],['2011/12/20,8'],['2011/12/14,4'],['2011/12/10,10'],['2011/12/9,7']]
with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for i in data:
        writer.writerow(i)


### Extract data from CSV ###
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as n:
    reader = csv.reader(n)
    dates = []
    freq = []
    for row in reader:
        values = row[0].split(',')
        dates.append(values[0])
        freq.append(values[1])          


### Do plot ###
false_x = [x for x in range(len(dates))]
plt.plot(false_x,freq, 'o-')
plt.xticks(range(len(dates)), (dates), rotation=45)
# plt.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]) - sets axes limits on graph
plt.axis([-1, 8, 0, 11])
plt.show()
```

This makes:

[image]

Comment: This example is using csv.reader and manually splitting the rows, which isn't necessary, and can cause problems on some csv files.  There's a question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46968044/why-do-i-need-to-add-quotes-to-this-csv-file/46968154#46968154) for a more detailed explanation.  Harpal's answer here helped me a lot getting into matplotlib though.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you look for something like:

```
import csv
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arch = 'C:\\Python26\\programas\\test.csv'
data = csv.reader(open(arch))

data = [(dt.datetime.strptime(item, "%Y/%m/%d"), float(value)) for item, value in data]
data.sort()
[x, y] = zip(*data)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y)

ax.grid(True)
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

[image]